# How to do a filter and get the result and then loop through it using rdd.collect()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following error after doing filter
with the following line

for row in dfCentralFilter.rdd.collect():

What do you recommend me to do to get the results using filter and then go through the results with a for loop

I leave my code in python so that you have a clearer idea of what I am doing

Thanks in advance

Python

```
import os
import sys

from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, Row
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

if __name__ =='__main__':
        conf=SparkConf().setAppName("Spark RDD").set("spark.speculation","true")
        sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
        sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
        sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

        rddCentral = sc.textFile("/user/imea/csv/archivo.csv")
        rddCentralMap = rddCentral.map(lambda line : line.split(","))

        print('paso 1')
        dfFields = ["AGE","NAME","CITY"]
        dfSchema = StructType([StructField(field_name, StringType(), True) for field_name in dfFields])
        dfCentral = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rddCentralMap, dfSchema)

        dfCentralFilter = dfCentral.filter("AGE > 10 and CITY = 'B'").orderBy("AGE","CITY", ascending=True)

        for row in dfCentralFilter.rdd.collect():
                print(row['AGE'])
                print(row['NAME'])
                print(row['CITY'])

        sc.stop()
```

Error

```
  File "/home/vfs/bin/Process2.py", line 26, in <module>
    for row in dfCentralFilter.rdd.collect():
```

CSV

```
10,Bob,A
20,Rog,A
30,Rose,B
40,Josh,B
50,John,C
```

Error
[image]

Comment: Please print the full error message. The code runs well in my environment. I get these 6 lines printed: `30` `Rose` `B` `40` `Josh` `B`

Comment: please share the error traceback as much as possible (or at least 2 paragraphs). the code seems fine.

Comment: @samkart I run the code with "spark-submit --queue=OID Process2.py" I took a screenshot of the error

Comment: It says `Cannot run program "python3"`. There's something not right with your Python/Spark setup. Your Spark part of the script does not even start to run. I can't help here sadly, I struggle too from time to time with my own setup of Spark.

Comment: check the path to python3 and/or explicitly mention it if you haven't